# How can i make in Xcode a layout for every device manually without using constraints

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, layout, constraints

I'm having some troubles in using constraints in Xcode to make the layout i want in every device (iPhone only), so i was wondering if there's a way to make manually every layout for each of the four iPhone displays

Comment: Don't be silly! Using constraints is far easier than creating a layout for each phone, if that's even possible. You must have some misunderstandings about constraints.

Comment: without constraints its hard to manage design

Comment: Yes, that's for sure, i have some misunderstandings, and that's why i would find it easier to manage it manually..so is there a way?

Comment: This is the attitude I used to take before I decided to grasp the constraints nettle. One day it just clicked and now I wouldn't consider anything else. I think the biggest hurdle is that Interface Builder's treatment of constraints is quirky to put it mildly.

Comment: @Alessandro Giovagnoli When you explain your issue please report some screenshots or some code about your situation so that people can help you to solve it. Read here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JeremyP You are right, i've now learned how to use constraints and it's much better

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do it Programmatically

if you need to auto layout a view you can set the autoresizingMask:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

> this will make the view width and height flexible and will flow
>   according to its superview

or if you subclass UIView override **layoutSubviews**:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.subview.frame = CGRect(0,0,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height);
}
```

layoutSubviews will be called whenever any adjustment needed.